# How to center blog post date/author contents on mobile page?

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

For whatever reason, I can't get this problem figured out; I'm trying to center my post's date and author contents on my mobile page. I can get the corresponding post title to center itself fine with "text-align: center" (which I'm not using currently, until the other issue is sorted out).

I've tried using margin 0 auto, and text-align, but can't seem to make things work. For anyone wondering, the !important tag seems to have no bearing either - I'd prefer to leave that out. Also, I have been utilizing the appropriate media queries.

My site is: www.tylercharboneauprofessional.com/international-pulse/net-neutrality

Here is an HTML-structure snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
article header {
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Hey @ashamun - I should've specified that I'm working with an unmodifiable template, so I cannot change the HTML. The most I can do is alter the CSS. However, those do not work, I've tried many combinations; it's the weirdest thing. Margin 0 auto has no effect on either class either. I feel like this shouldn't be as difficult as it's being.

Comment: Sorry, I was on mobile but just got back to the computer. This should work for you: `article header {text-align: center;}`

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! Write that in as a full answer, and I'll be happy to grant full credit :)

Comment: @TCharb Thanks. Updated answer above.